# How to achieve such justification?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, justification

I want my text to be forcibly justified on the left and right and not just centred on the page. I know this,

```latex
\begin{center}
Elizabeth it is in vain you say
"Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
\end{center}
```

yields something like,

```
                           Elizabeth it is in vain you say
                   "Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
```

But I want,

```
                  |Elizabeth    it   is   in    vain   you    say|
                  |"Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:|
```

I am using `polyglossia` and want to accomplish this in the "other" language that uses the Arabic alphabet. I have tried the justify environment by `ragged2e` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: justification is the default in latex, please always show a complete small document that shows the problem.  If you did not use the `center`  enviornment the text would be justified (set `\parfillskip=0pt` if you want the last line of a paragraph full length)

Answer (score 7):

Justification is the default in LaTeX, so you don't need to specify it, just don't specify `center`. You can set `\parfillskip` to 0pt if you want the last line of a paragraph always stretched full length.

If you mean that you want to center a block of justified text set to less than the text width, you can center a `minipage` so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}\sloppy
Elizabeth it is in vain you say

"Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{300pt}\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}\sloppy
Elizabeth it is in vain you say

"Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{250pt}\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}\sloppy
Elizabeth it is in vain you say

"Love not" — thou sayest it in so sweet a way:
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```